# drop specific Vertices that may not exist

Tags: typescript, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

**I would like to drop specific vertices from my Neptune graph.** I get a list of id's from outside Neptune and wish to drop all of them. **Problem is, some of them may not exist.**

I tried this, but it seems I can't hand over an array:

```
g.V(['1', '12', '14']).drop().iterate()
```

I also tried stringing single drop operations together with store, aggregate or sideEffect, but as soon as one of the vertices doesn't exists, the call doesn't delete anything...

```
g.addV('test').property(id, '1')
  .addV('test').property(id, '12')

g.V('1').aggregate('x')
  .V('12').aggregate('x')
  .V('13').aggregate('x')
  .select('x').unfold().drop()
```

(I can iterate over the list and string a query together, but of course this never works with
`V('1').drop().V('12).drop()`)

I'm using typescript around the gremlin code.
Neptune runs with gremlin: {'version': 'tinkerpop-3.4.11'}

Comment: I was not able to reproduce what you are seeing just using Gremlin - I'll try the Javascript client also just to make sure but as Stephen notes below, your Gremlin looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is the correct way to write your traversal - passing a `List` of `id` should work:

```
g.V(['1', '12', '14']).drop().iterate()
```

you could alternatively do any of the following (and other variations):

```
g.V('1', '12', '14').drop().iterate()
g.V().hasId('1', '12', '14').drop().iterate()
g.V().hasId(within['1', '12', '14']).drop().iterate()
```

They should all equate to the first one though.